# Create index based on foreign key relation

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

I have a Django model with a ForeignKey relation to another model:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
```

My Django-generated database PostgreSQL tables are `myapp_author` and `myapp_book`, the latter being defined by:

```
CREATE TABLE "myapp_book" (
    "id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "author_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "myapp_author" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED,
    ...
);
```

What is the **PostgreSQL command** to create an index on the `myapp_book` table based on one of the fields of the `Author` model (let's call it `gender`)?

Answer (score 0):

This creates a B-tree index named `author_indx` on table `Book` based on `author_id`

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX author_indx ON Book (author_id);
```

You can read more [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createindex.html)

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I am looking for. I want to improve the speed of queries of the type "get all the books of female authors". I think your solution only affects queries such as "get all the books of author Shakespeare".